# Ctrl + Space autocomplete won't work in eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I have looked at everything on page 1 of [ctrl + space not working in eclipse](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=strict&q=ctrl%20%2B%20space%20not%20working%20in%20eclipse) in google. Im using eclipse on windows 7 in java.

I have checked:

1. windows -> preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist -> advanced -> java proposals checked on
2. Windows, Control panel –> Region and language options –> Advance tab –> Language for non-unicode program –> and made sure English(US) was selected
3. I have also looked up how to check if eclipse is hijacked but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Windows->Preferences->General->Keys` and check key binding for content assist. If not there set it Control+Space

Comment: Content assited is set to ctrl+space. I should probably mention that the first time I press ctrl+space, eclipse freezes for like 20 seconds and still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Window--->Preference--->Java--->Editor--->Content assist 
PLACE BELOW TEXT NEXT TO AUTO-ACITVATION TRIGERRS FOR JAVA
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Just now tested and it works..:)